# E-R diagram 1-to-1 mandatory relationship for two superclass entities to relational schema

Tags: erd, rdbms

How are two superclass entities that are connected to a mandatory 1-to-1 relationship converted to relational schemas? These two superclass entities are also abstract, meaning that they will not have a table, but their descendants will. Most probably the descendants tables' are somehow combined, but how?

Comment: *mandatory 1-to-1 relationship*? it cannot be realized in practice, because the data cannot be inserted into such structure (intermediate state 1-to-zero will occur). It must be 1-to-(0 or 1). I.e. One of entities must be "primary" and the another one must have UNIQUE constraint over the relational expression.

Comment: I've heard that these kinds of entities (that are connected with a mandatory 1-to-1 relationship) are combined into one relational schema during the conversion of the E-R diagram to relational schemas. Isn't that special case true?  Does this notation exist just for better organization?

Comment: @Akina - It can be realized by setting one of the FKs to `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. With that setting, the FK isn't checked until `COMMIT` is called.  But, that might be an Oracle thing. From (bad) experience, its an impractical physical design.  In the end, I did not achieve the performance increase that I expected by splitting  the data  across two  tables. In fact, I lost more time towards SW Development then I gained in DB search performance.

Comment: @MichaelKutz This is DBMS-dependent whereas OP asks in general.